# Excel Filter Function - Select the Spill Columns to Return

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

I have a range of columns which I'm needed to use the FILTER function to spill the column values if the record's value is = to a specific text. This I've nailed, however now I'd like to do this for multiple columns and spill the FILTER within only select columns.

My result with this formula is great but not what I need:

```
=FILTER(TableName[ColumnReturnArray],TableName[ColumnCheckValue]="someText")
```

I'm attempting this:

```
=FILTER(TableName[@[ColumnReturnArray1]:[ColumnReturnArray4]],TableName[ColumnCheckValue]="someText")
```

This is where I'm stuck, I'm getting an error returned `#Value`, what am I doing wrong? How can I specify the columns I'd like to return in the spill? Maybe is there a way to use the `AND` along with `FILTER`?

Comment: You have an extra `)` in the middle of the formula.

Comment: And remove the `@`

Comment: So, I attempted this with using 'FILTER' function. However, I still is returning a all columns between the columns I'm trying to isolate.

'=FILTER(Sheet1[[ColumnReturnArray3]:[ColumnReturnArray1]],Sheet1[ColumnCheckValue]="someText")'

My desired return would only to spill the selected columns, "ColumnReturnArray3" & "ColumnReturnArray1" but nothing between.

Comment: I think what you mean might be: `=FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(TableName,4,1),TableName[ColumnCheckValue]="someText")`

Comment: Try `=FILTER(HSTACK(TableName[ColumnReturnArray1],TableName[ColumnReturnArray4]),TableName[ColumnCheckValue]="someText")`.